# R label with commas but no decimals

Tags: r, ggplot2, format

My goal is to produce labels with commas, but no decimals. Let's say I have a ggplot with the following section:

```
geom_text(aes(y = var,
              label = scales::comma(round(var))), hjust = 0, nudge_y = 300 )
```

This is almost what I need. It gives me the commas, but has a decimal. I have seen here ([axis labels with comma but no decimals ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50690198/axis-labels-with-comma-but-no-decimals-ggplot)) that `comma_format()` could be good, but I think the label in my case needs a data argument, which `comma_format()` does not take. What can I do?

Update:

As an example of when this problem occurs, see the following, which uses `gganimate` and has a lot more going on. Code derived from Jon Spring's answer at [Animated sorted bar chart with bars overtaking each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162821/animated-sorted-bar-chart-with-bars-overtaking-each-other)

```
library(gapminder)
library(gganimate)
library(tidyverse)

gap_smoother <- gapminder %>%
    filter(continent == "Asia") %>%
    group_by(country) %>%
    complete(year = full_seq(year, 1)) %>%
    mutate(gdpPercap = spline(x = year, y = gdpPercap, xout = year)$y) %>%
    group_by(year) %>%
    mutate(rank = min_rank(-gdpPercap) * 1) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    group_by(country) %>%
    complete(year = full_seq(year, .5)) %>%
    mutate(gdpPercap = spline(x = year, y = gdpPercap, xout = year)$y) %>%
    mutate(rank =      approx(x = year, y = rank,      xout = year)$y) %>%
    ungroup()  %>% 
    arrange(country,year)

gap_smoother2 <- gap_smoother %>% filter(year<=2007 & year>=1999)
gap_smoother3 <- gap_smoother2 %<>% filter(rank<=8)


p <- ggplot(gap_smoother3, aes(rank, group = country, 
                               fill = as.factor(country), color = as.factor(country))) +
    geom_tile(aes(y = gdpPercap/2,
                  height = gdpPercap,
                  width = 0.9), alpha = 0.8, color = NA) +
    geom_text(aes(y = 0, label = paste(country, " ")), vjust = 0.2, hjust = 1) +
    geom_text(aes(y = gdpPercap,
                  label = scales::comma(round(gdpPercap))), hjust = 0, nudge_y = 300 ) +
    coord_flip(clip = "off", expand = FALSE) +
    scale_x_reverse() +
    guides(color = FALSE, fill = FALSE) +
    labs(title='{closest_state %>% as.numeric %>% floor}', 
         x = "", y = "GFP per capita") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0, size = 22),
          axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),  # These relate to the axes post-flip
          axis.text.y  = element_blank(),  # These relate to the axes post-flip
          plot.margin = margin(1,1,1,4, "cm")) +
    transition_states(year, transition_length = 1, state_length = 0) +
    enter_grow() +
    exit_shrink() +
    ease_aes('linear') 

animate(p, fps = 2, duration = 5, width = 600, height = 500)
```

Comment: Can you add a small reproducible example?

Comment: I made a small reproducible example, but it actually worked in that one (no decimal). My actual application is also included—I apologize that it is much longer; this is where it doesn't work (it displays one 0 after a decimal).

Comment: You provided a *small* reproducible example but *"it actually worked"* (does not show your problem) ... how is that "reproducible"?

Comment: Good point. My apologies. I deleted that part.

Comment: Does `labels = scales::comma(round(var), accuracy=1)` not work?

Comment: Yes, adding `accuracy=1` works. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to the solution provided by @drf, you need to add `scale_y_continuous(scales::comma)` to your ggplot commands. But put it *before* the `coord_flip` function.

```
p <- ggplot(gap_smoother3, aes(rank, group = country, 
                               fill = as.factor(country), color = as.factor(country))) +
  geom_tile(aes(y = gdpPercap/2,
                height = gdpPercap,
                width = 0.9), alpha = 0.8, color = NA) +
  geom_text(aes(y = gdpPercap,
                label = scales::comma(round(gdpPercap), accuracy=1)), 
            hjust = 0, nudge_y = 300 ) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
... etc.
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I think the other thing that it needs is the suggestion from @drf to add the `accuracy=1` option. That gets rid of the `.0` at the end of the labels.

Comment: But there is no `.0` at the end.

Comment: In the labels of the bars or in the x-axis?