# Axis with label = comma without showing decimals for large numbers

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I have an x-axis in logscale, and I would like to display the labels without scientific notation (*i.e.* not `1e3`, but `1,000` instead). I have always done this with `label = scales::comma`, but now my dataset also has very small values (`0.001`, for instance). Hence, when I add `+ scale_x_log10(label = comma)`, I get an x-axis where `1e-3` looks like `0.001` (as it should), but `1e3` looks like `1,000.000`. I would like to remove the three decimal places, so that instead of `1,000.000` I just have `1,000`. Using `label = comma_format(accuracy = 1)`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50690198/axis-labels-with-comma-but-no-decimals-ggplot) will make values like `0.001` look just like `0`, so it's not a valid option.

Anyone has any idea?
Here there is a reproducible example of the problem:

```
library(ggplot2)

X <- 10^seq(-3, 3, length.out = 50)
Y <- 100 * X/(X + 1)
Demo_data <- data.frame(X, Y)

ggplot(Demo_data, aes(x = X, y = Y)) + geom_line(size = 1.5) + 
  scale_x_log10(breaks = c(1e-3, 1e-2, 1e-1, 1, 10, 1e2, 1e3),
                label = scales::comma)
```

This solution does not work:

```
ggplot(Demo_data, aes(x = X, y = Y)) + geom_line(size = 1.5) + 
      scale_x_log10(breaks = c(1e-3, 1e-2, 1e-1, 1, 10, 1e2, 1e3),
                    label = scales::comma_format(accuracy = 1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use an `ifelse` to conditionally set the `accuracy` for values > 1 and < 1:

```r
X <- 10^seq(-3, 3, length.out = 50)
Y <- 100 * X / (X + 1)
Demo_data <- data.frame(X, Y)

library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot(Demo_data, aes(x = X, y = Y)) +
  geom_line(size = 1.5) +
  scale_x_log10(
    breaks = c(1e-3, 1e-2, 1e-1, 1, 10, 1e2, 1e3),
    label = ~ ifelse(.x < 1, scales::comma(.x), scales::comma(.x, accuracy = 1))
  )
#> Warning: Using `size` aesthetic for lines was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use `linewidth` instead.
```

[image]